# How can I resize the recaptcha in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, captcha

I want to re size the text from the captcha to be easier to see, with Greasemonkey.

How can I do it?

For example, I have this captcha:

```
<div id="recaptcha_image" style="width: 300px; height: 57px; ">
  <img style="display:block;" height="57" width="300" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuuqeICMpU36GlHCSchBzERwiDzTH4A1RHobtEpbbSK5lWC47EVkgeuF_ause8bnYTHGhjRr_GFiVMh9e4sZFXIBlv4-vcY7WXNjtBHhVmIl2Z5tqK_CY5hRZjtr-MWDUrBOr7mQE0ZqfU8XeeUeXLM5cxcwEQ">
</div>
```

I want to change the `height="57"` and the `width="300"` from the second line (from the image style) to 85 and 450 respectively.

Changing it into the inspect works correctly, but how can I do to do it always with Greasemonkey?

Comment: you cannot use document.getElementById('reaptcha_image').style.height="85px";
??

Comment: note if you copied and pasted what mplungjan wrote it won't work it should be `document.getElementById('recaptcha_image').style.height="85px";`
The c was missing in the recapta part of the name.

Comment: this command only enlarge the box of the captcha, and not the text itself

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('recaptcha_image').firstChild.style.height="85px";` to change the size of the image (recaptcha "text") itself. Also, as recaptcha's are in an iframe, if you are accessing it from the parent frame you will need to use `recaptchIframe.document.getElementById('recaptcha_image').firstChild.style.height="85px";` where `recaptchIframe` is the iframe of the recaptcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `userContent.css` entries might work:

```
div#recaptcha_image,
div#recaptcha_image > img {
  width: 450px !important;
  height: 85px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Greasemonkey, I'm going to assume you're using a reasonably up-to-date version of Firefox. In which case, you might be able to use querySelector:

```
var query = document.querySelector("#recaptcha_image > img");
if (query) {
    query.style.width = "450px !important";
    query.style.height = "85px !important";
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can try setting the img's attributes instead:

```
var query = document.querySelector("#recaptcha_image > img");
if (query) {
    query.setAttribute("width", "450");
    query.setAttribute("height", "85");
}
```

If **that** doesn't work, you can try setting both the box and the img:

```
var element = document.getElementById("recaptcha_image");
if (element) {
    element.style.width = "450px !important";
    element.style.height = "85px !important";
}

var query = element.querySelector("img");
if (query) {
    query.setAttribute("width", "450");
    query.setAttribute("height", "85");
}
```

Comment: @idealmachine: In the link you gave me, it states that you need to set each style individually, and that setAttribute won't work. Perhaps you misread it?

Comment: You're right, I *did* misread it. It's *custom properties* that need to be set using setAttribute. http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.2310:_style

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
var img = document.evaluate("//div[@id='recaptcha_image']/img", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
img.setAttribute('width', '85');
img.setAttribute('height', '450');
```

If the recaptcha is in an iframe, then @include the iframe's url, and not the parent's url, but note that this'll probably change the size of recaptcha's on every site, so you may want to check that `window.top.location` for [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.top) is the desired location.